# "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'. - Postman

Tags: asp.net-web-api, postman

I have an `Api` controller: `UserController`

Inside of this controller I have this method :

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
[ActionName("SignUp")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]FormDataCollection formData)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage MyHttpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError); ....
      .....
    }
```

I want to debug it in Postman but I always get this error:

```
 "Message": "The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."
```

[image]

I've tried to add just to set the `url` in different ways in Postman, but still this problem:

```
http://localhost:59694/api/user - with Post, I've deleted the `ActionName attribute` from controller.
```

I've checked the `RouteConfig.cs`, I have this:

```
  routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
```

Can you please advise?

Comment: Try `public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] string action, [FormBody] string invite_id)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Web api not supporting POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494784/web-api-not-supporting-post-method)